# Window.close(), java script method is not working for Chome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Window.close(), java script method is not working for Chrome. I am trying to close (non Pop up) window which was not open through JS. I have tried almost all the alternatives but none worked.Please share if u have any suitable JS code to close chrome browser window.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) For one thing, it's very hard for us to help you with code we cannot see (because you didn't include it in your question). Context is also useful: What window? If your code didn't open it, where did it come from? How did you get a reference to it?

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons you are only allowed to close windows with JavaScript which were opened with JavaScript. When executing `window.close` in a tab, which was not programmatically opened, then Chrome 47 warns you with:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: Thanks Benny. Actually i was more curious to know if it can be done on Chrome like IE an how?

Comment: What you are asking for is unfortunately not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the window wasn't opened by your code, most browsers won't let you close it. This does vary a bit browser by browser, but in general, closing a window you didn't open is a dodgy thing to do, and browsers don't let you do it.

Assuming you *did* open the window (with `window.open` or a `target` attribute on a form or some such), you'd close it by getting a reference to it (say, into a variable called `wnd`) and the calling `close`: `wnd.close();`. To close the current window (if you can), it's `window.close();` (not `Window.close();` as in your question).

Comment: I am sorry T.J. it was window.close() only. This is working with IE but not with chrome. Is there any alternative way to do this for chrome.

Comment: @user3282710: If you didn't open the window, no, I don't think so. And I wouldn't expect that IE will keep doing it forever, either.

Comment: So, is there any way to close Chrome browser forcefully through code, or we could find the close browser functionality.

Comment: @user3282710: For the **third time**: *"If you didn't open the window, no, I don't think so."*